# There are 12 seats in the first row of a theater,of which 4 are to be occupied.Find the number of ways so that each person has exactly one neighbour?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There must be at least one seat between a pair. In this way each person can have exactly one neighbour.

Let the number of seats between the pairs be $y$ excluding the one seat and before and after the pair be $x$ and $z$
We know $x+y+z=7$
$$(x^0+x^1+x^2+......+x^7)^2(x)(1+x+x^2+....+x^6)$$
Now we have to find the coefficient of $x^6$ in the above expression which is equal to $8C2=28$.

And the number of ways in which $4$ people can sit on $4$ chairs is $4!$.
So the answer should be $28 \cdot 4!=672$ but the answer is $864$. Help me in correcting my mistake.

Comment: Can you just choose 2 pairs of seats and then choose who sits where, then subtract the number of pairings that are next to each other?

Comment: Is that $x$ in the middle of your product of generating polynomials supposed to be a multiplication symbol?  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Sorry my mistake..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So...the pattern is $S^aP_1S^bP_2S^c$ where $a,c$ are non-negative integers, $b$ is a positive integer,  and $a+b+c=8$. Here, "$S$" denotes a space, that is, an unoccupied seat. $P_i$ denote the two pairs of occupied seats. Letting $b_1=b-1$ we want to compute the number of $3-$ tuples of non-negative integers that sum to $7$.  Stars and Bars tells us that there are $$\binom {7+3-1}2=\binom {9}2=36$$ such triples $(a,b_1,c)$.

Given a triple there are $4!=24$ ways to populate the pairs.  Hence the answer is $$24\times 36=864$$ as desired.

Comment: "There are 24 ways to populate" Did you get 24 by $\binom42 \cdot 2!\cdot 2!$ ?

Comment: I came across another similar question with $14$ chairs and $6$ persons? I got $\binom96 \binom62 \cdot 2!\cdot 2!\cdot 2!$ but the given answer is simply $\binom96 6!$ What's wrong?

Comment: @Wolgwang  There are $4$ people.  Once we have specified where the people are going to sit, then there $4!=24$ ways to select the order in which the people will take the seats.